# Should We Have a [workbench-render-engine] Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have a tag for [cycles-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles-render-engine) , [eevee-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eevee-render-engine) and [blender-internal-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal-render-engine) but not an active tag for [workbench-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workbench-render-engine)

I created the tag on an edit to a question recently when I noticed this, but it seems that the system has deleted the tag as an orphan.

As of this writing, we have roughly [24 questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=workbench%20engine%20is%3Aquestion) referring to Workbench, so while it may not be the most popular engine, it may help organization in the long run.

Thoughts?

Comment: I have no objections.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late to the party. I don't mind if there is a tag for Workbench, I'm usually not using the engine but others do. At the moment I'm more concerned about the blender-internal-render-engine because I see it used quite often recently, although many of those users are using versions 2.8x / 2.9x and therefore Cycles or Eevee. I guess they confuse "internal render engine" with some "external render engine" like LuxCoreRender, Octane etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, definitely. As a default builtin render engine it deserves a place among other more popular entries.

It belongs in out tag system along with all other render-engines tags [cycles-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles-render-engine), [blender-internal-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blender-internal-render-engine), [eevee-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eevee-render-engine) ,[luxrender-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luxrender-render-engine), [renderman-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/renderman-render-engine), [octane-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/octane-render-engine) and [radeon-prorender-render-engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radeon-prorender-render-engine).

I'll tag those questions with it so the system doesn't delete the tag.